# Cruise Control Net Task Fail IF File Exist

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

We are using cruise control net for automating our build. We are keeping the installation created with automated build in a shared folder.

We want to stop the build with an error message in the build fail mail, if an installation is available in the shared folder. This is to prevent deleting installation files created in a previous build accidentally

Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is possible you can first test one  file of your installation that must exist if installation is available (like a config file or executable file)

```
 <conditional>
  <conditions>
    <fileExistsCondition>
      <file>installationFile.nottodelete.config</file>
    </fileExistsCondition>
  </conditions>
  <tasks>
    <!-- Tasks to perform if condition passed -->
    <!-- send mail here -->
  </tasks>
  <elseTasks>
    <!-- Tasks to perform if condition failed -->
      <!-- continue so nothing to do -->
  </elseTasks>
</conditional>
```